# subquery wilth alias is failing with identifier 'T1.C0'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT t1.c0, t1.c1::VARCHAR(16777216), t1.c2::VARCHAR(16777216), t1.c3::VARCHAR(16777216), t1.c4::VARCHAR(16777216) FROM (SELECT (t0."PERSONID"::NUMBER(38, 0))::DOUBLE, t0."LASTNAME"::VARCHAR(255), t0."FIRSTNAME"::VARCHAR(255), t0."ADDRESS"::VARCHAR(255), t0."CITY"::VARCHAR(255) FROM "PERSONS_SNW" AS t0) AS t1 (c0, c1, c2, c3, c4) WHERE c0 = 1
```

Above sql is failing with SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier 'T1.C0'
Why can't we append select alias name with column alias name?

```
SELECT c0, c1::VARCHAR(16777216), c2::VARCHAR(16777216), c3::VARCHAR(16777216), c4::VARCHAR(16777216) FROM (SELECT (t0."PERSONID"::NUMBER(38, 0))::DOUBLE, t0."LASTNAME"::VARCHAR(255), t0."FIRSTNAME"::VARCHAR(255), t0."ADDRESS"::VARCHAR(255), t0."CITY"::VARCHAR(255) FROM "PERSONS_SNW" AS t0) AS t1 (c0, c1, c2, c3, c4) WHERE c0 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Snowflake can not handle column aliases for subqueries (for now). Maybe you can submit a support ticket about it. Not sure if it's a bug or it's not supported intentionally.

```
-- not working
SELECT t1.c0 FROM 
(SELECT v1,v2 from testy) as t1(c0, c1);

-- working if you define alias in subquery
SELECT t1.c0 FROM 
(SELECT v1 c0, v2 from testy) as t1;

-- working if you use CTE instead of subquery
with t1 (c0, c1)  as 
(SELECT * from testy)
SELECT t1.c0 FROM t1;
```

You may define alias in subquery or you may use CTE instead of subquery.

Comment: sure i'll raise a support ticket.